# How to find similar words or sentences from two cells in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want a space between these example sentences:

```
a1: book by me, show by me
a2: show by me, book by me
```

In this problem I want to keep a space between them.

```
Function DupeWord(str1 As String, str2 As String) As String
    Dim vArr1
    Dim vArr2
    Dim vTest
    Dim lngCnt As Long
    vArr1 = Split(Replace(str1, " ", vbNullString), ",")
    vArr2 = Split(Replace(str2, " ", vbNullString), ",")
    On Error GoTo strExit
     
    For lngCnt = LBound(vArr1) To UBound(vArr1)
        vTest = Application.Match(vArr1(lngCnt), vArr2, 0)
        If Not IsError(vTest) Then DupeWord = DupeWord & vArr1(lngCnt) & ", "
    Next lngCnt
    If Len(DupeWord) > 0 Then

    Else
strExit:
        DupeWord = "No Matches!"
    End If
End Function
```